# Show that $x \mapsto \frac{\|x\|^2}{2}+\cos\|x\|$ is strictly convex.

Tags: convex-analysis

I'm trying to solve a past year exam question. I'm having trouble with this question.

I have to show that the following function is strictly convex.
$$f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, \\  x \mapsto \frac{\|x\|^2}{2}+\cos\|x\|,$$

where $\|\cdot \|$ is the Euclidean norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I wanted to compute the Hessian. To do so, I wanted to use the fact that this function is constant on any sphere. Since $f$ is constant on any sphere, the gradient is perpendicular to the sphere at any point on the sphere. But I'm not sure how to proceed. I've showed that this function is convex by decomposing it as $u \circ v$ with  $v$ the norm and $u$ as $x^2/2 + \cos(x)$. I showed that $v$ is convex and that $u$ is convex and increasing.

Comment: Please show what you have tried.

Comment: Well I wanted to compute the hessian to do so i wanted to use the fact that this  function is constant on any sphere. Since  f is constant on any sphere , the gradient is perpendicular to the sphere at any point on the sphere.But I'm not sure how to proceed. I've showed that this function is convex  by decomposing it as  g o f with the g the norm and f  as x² /2 + cos(x). I showed that g is convex and that f is convex and increasing.

Comment: Please add this to your OP

Comment: In general, it is frowned upon to include phrases like "help please" in the title of your post.

Comment: ok I changed the title.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the function $g:\mathbb R^+\rightarrow \mathbb R$ given by $g\left(t\right) =\frac{t^2}2 + \cos t$.

We have $g’\left(t\right)=t-\sin t > 0$ so that $g$ is strictly increasing.

Suppose $r<s$. Then
$$\begin{align}
\sin s -\sin r&=2\sin\left(\frac{s-r}2\right)\cos\left(\frac{s+r}2\right) \\
&\leq 2\sin\left(\frac{s-r}2\right) \\
&<2\frac{s-r}2 \\
&=s-r
\end{align}$$ so that $g’$ is strictly increasing.
This implies that $g$ is strictly convex.

Suppose $x\neq y$ and $0<\lambda<1$.

If $\left\Vert x\right\Vert \neq\left\Vert y\right\Vert$ then
$$ \begin{align}
f\left(\lambda x + \left(1-\lambda\right)y\right) &= g\left(\left\Vert \lambda x + \left(1-\lambda\right)y\right\Vert\right) \\
&\leq g\left(\lambda\left\Vert x \right\Vert + \left(1-\lambda\right)\left\Vert y\right\Vert\right) \\
&< \lambda g\left(\left\Vert x\right\Vert\right)+\left(1-\lambda\right)g\left(\left\Vert y \right\Vert\right) \\
&=\lambda f\left(x\right)+\left(1-\lambda\right)f\left(y\right)
\end{align}$$
where the first inequality holds because $g$ is strictly increasing and the second because it is strictly convex.

If $\left\Vert x\right\Vert = \left\Vert y\right\Vert$ then $\lambda x+\left(1-\lambda\right)y$ is an interior point of the ball of radius $\left\Vert x\right\Vert $ ($=\left\Vert y\right\Vert$). Then $\left\Vert \lambda x+\left(1-\lambda\right)y\right\Vert <\left\Vert x\right\Vert $ so that
$$ \begin{align}
f\left(\lambda x + \left(1-\lambda\right)y\right) &= g\left(\left\Vert \lambda x + \left(1-\lambda\right)y\right\Vert\right) \\
&< g\left(\left\Vert x \right\Vert\right) \\
&= \lambda g\left(\left\Vert x\right\Vert\right)+\left(1-\lambda\right)g\left(\left\Vert x \right\Vert\right) \\
&= \lambda g\left(\left\Vert x\right\Vert\right)+\left(1-\lambda\right)g\left(\left\Vert y \right\Vert\right) \\
&=\lambda f\left(x\right)+\left(1-\lambda\right)f\left(y\right)
\end{align}$$
where the inequality holds since $g$ is strictly increasing.

This proves that $f$ is strictly convex.

Comment: This was [my first (now deleted) proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/4589542/1). Alas (see tomtomgps's comment below my - now different - answer) your strict inequality fails if $\|x\|=\|y\|.$

Comment: You're right! I updated my answer with the missing case. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**First answer**

You were almost there!

$f=u\circ v$ with $v(x)=\|x\|$ and $u(t)=\frac{t^2}2+\cos t.$

Since $v$ is *strictly* convex and $u$ is *strictly* convex and increasing, $f$ is strictly convex.

**Second answer**

For $x\ne0,$ let $t:=\|x\|>0.$

The first and second differentials of $f$ at $x$ are given by:
$$df_x(h)=\langle x,h\rangle\left(1-\frac{\sin t}t\right),
$$
$$d^2f_x(h,k)=\langle h,k\rangle\left(1-\frac{\sin t}t\right)-\langle x,h\rangle\langle x,k\rangle\frac{t\cos t-\sin t}{t^3}
$$
hence if $t\notin2\pi\Bbb Z$:

- for all $h$ linearily independent from $x,$
  $$\begin{align}t^3d^2f_x(h,h)&=\|h\|^2\|x\|^2\left(t-\sin t\right)-\langle x,h\rangle^2\left(t\cos t-\sin t\right)\\
  &>\langle x,h\rangle^2t\left(1-\cos t\right)\ge0,\end{align}$$
- for $h=\lambda x$ with $\lambda\ne0,$
  $$d^2f_x(h,h)=\|h\|^2\left(1-\cos t\right)>0.$$

This proves that $d^2f_x$ is positive definite for all $x$ such that $\|x\|\notin2\pi\Bbb Z.$ So,  the set of "bad" $x$'s contains no non-trivial segment,  hence $f$ is strictly convex.

Comment: Thanks for your answer , how did you show that u is strictly convex ?

Comment: $u''(t)=1-\cos t>0$ on $\Bbb R\setminus2\pi\Bbb Z.$

Comment: I don't think what you wrote works. if v is only convex then v(x) and v(y) are not necessarily different (take v as a constant function as an example) even though x different than y, so when you apply u the strictly convex function you do not have the strict inequality.

Comment: Sorry, you are right! Here is a completely new proof, following your first idea to compute the Hessian.

Comment: I fact my old proof was nearly ok, so I re-inserted it (just adding that the Euclidean norm $v$  is *strictly* convex).